# Can not play rtsp stream from Youtube

Tags: android, youtube-api

i'm trying since a few days to play Youtube rtsp streams in my Android app,
but only get Errors from Android MediaPlayer instance - unable to open file.

I've tried to open 3gp files, it can play. Tried to open other rtsp streams found
around the internet - all can play, but Youtube dont.

Tested the video urls in Windows VLC player - the player cant play a YOutube video
streamed with rtsp protocol.

Is there something wrong with YT rtsp streams so no player can play that Urls?

Thanks for a small hint what can i try to do ;)

Comment: have you given the permission?

Comment: How do you get the URL from a youtube video ? The unofficials APIs that allows this get deprecated all the time as Google often changes the parameters to pass to the Youtube servers.

Comment: Yes, the app have the internet permission - if you meant this?

I used the common feed API to query about a video:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/VIDEO_ID?format=1&v=2

format=1 means the 3gp mobile Version with H263 support, this is, what i 've read from the documentation

Comment: Seems now, problem is solved. it wasnt my code - it's my network router: rtsp was'nt opened for UDP :)